# Find sum of matching words in sentence according to list of words

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp

I have data containing two variables (sentence and b), like this. I want to find the sum of words in b according to the sentence. Then i save in sum variable

```
          sentence                        b
i like coffee better than tea        'coffee', 'tea'
because coffee can make me stay 
happy
```

I want the output like this, any two words of coffee in the sentence and one word of tea in the sentence so the sum of words is three that i save in sum variable.

```
          sentence                        b                    sum
i like coffee better than tea        'coffee', 'tea'            3
because coffee can make me stay 
happy
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the str.count() function, it returns the number of occurrence of the provided substring in a string.

```py
for i in b:
    sumOfWords += sentence.count(i)
```

Comment: please note that `sum()` is [a built-in function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp) so your usage would shadow the function. (yes, I know OP asked for it to be in the variable `sum`)

Comment: Please do **not** recommend naming a variable `sum`.